# HTML How to Transition Between Pages

Tags: html

I am currently trying to make a transition between pages on a website.

Eg: If a user were on www.example.com/About and they clicked on a link to go to www.example.com/Contact, the about page would fly out to the left, whilst the contact page would fly in from the right.

So far all I could find online was how to do this on the same page with hashtags. But I want to do this with separate pages.

is it possible?
if not is there an alternative and how to do it?

**UPDATE**

Ok so I did a bit more research and I found this thing called barba.js(http://barbajs.org) that seemed to do what I'm looking for. So I installed the js script file followed the instructions on the site...and it didn't work! All it did was not load my pages correctly and didn't do what it was supposed to do. Anyone know how I can use this(or if there is a better option than barba.js).

-Thanks!

Comment: *Anything* is possible, is it hard? *Yes*. Have you tried anything we can help you with? *No*.

Comment: You should use AJAX to reload the code inside the `<body>` tag of the current page with that of the next page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with pure html &  js, as you load the entire page each time you click on a link if it's not an anchor.

However you can load just a part of the page,  and so apply a transition of your choice with Ajax and js

But in the end, you won't really switch from page to page, but only load the parts that you want to update. This is approximately how modern front end frameworks like Angular, React,...  are working

Here is a pure js example http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_first

Here is a jQuery example http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm just struggling to get it to work with my HTML(I am very new to java!). How could I implement the code you linked with a transition?

Comment: I think simple css rules like `transition` should do it, if you apply it to your body

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about is page transition and it normally happens in SPA (Single Page Application) where there is no hard refresh.

If you are not working in a SPA application I don't think you can do that where you are moving from one page to another by link/button click and a hard refresh happens.

You can choose angularjs one of the famous spa/mvc framework in jvascript and us ui-router to move from one page to another. there are many other you can explore.