# Barba Js Not Working

Tags: html

Ok, so recently I asked a question on transitioning between pages for HTML([HTML How to Transition Between Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145395/html-how-to-transition-between-pages)). So I found this thing called barba.js so I got it and...it didn't work. I searched for a while and there was practically no easy to follow or clear documentation or instructions.

Here is the code for my page(all the pages code are the same)

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<div id="barba-wrapper">
<div class="barba-container">
<html lang="en">

    <body background="Img1.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" type = "text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="barba.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="http://d36mw5gp02ykm5.cloudfront.net/yc/adrns_y.js?v=6.10.505#p=wdcxwd5000bevt-22a0rt0_wd-wx21a706024960249";var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);})();</script></head>
    <script src="nextprev.js"></script>
    <script src="TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center><big><font size="15">A Beach Somewhere</font></big></center>
    <center><h3><b><a href="Page2.html">Next&#10140;</a></b></h3></center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
    <br>

    </body>

</html>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to use barba.js because from the description on the website it sounded exactly what I wanted, but if there is a better alternative that would be great, but I would preferably like a solution to my problem

-Thanks!

**UPDATE**
So I've now changed some of my code but it is still not working.
HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <body background="Img1.png">
    <main id="barba-wrapper" data-prev="" data-next="Page2.html">
    <div class="barba-container">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" type = "text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center><big><font size="15">A Beach Somewhere</font></big></center>
    <center><h3><b><a href="Page2.html" class="nav next">Next&#10140;</a></b></h3></center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>


    </div>
    </main>

    </body>

</html>

<script src="barba.js"></script>
<script src="nextprev.js"></script>
<script src="TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        Barba.Pjax.start();
      });
</script>
```

CSS.css:

```
font{
    size:25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    }

body {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #555;
}


.barba-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

nextprev.js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lastElementClicked;
  var PrevLink = document.querySelector('a.prev');
  var NextLink = document.querySelector('a.next');

  Barba.Pjax.init();
  Barba.Prefetch.init();

  Barba.Dispatcher.on('linkClicked', function(el) {
    lastElementClicked = el;
  });

  var MovePage = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
    start: function() {
      this.originalThumb = lastElementClicked;

      Promise
        .all([this.newContainerLoading, this.scrollTop()])
        .then(this.movePages.bind(this));
    },

    scrollTop: function() {
      var deferred = Barba.Utils.deferred();
      var obj = { y: window.pageYOffset };

      TweenLite.to(obj, 0.4, {
        y: 0,
        onUpdate: function() {
          if (obj.y === 0) {
            deferred.resolve();
          }

          window.scroll(0, obj.y);
        },
        onComplete: function() {
          deferred.resolve();
        }
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    },

    movePages: function() {
      var _this = this;
      var goingForward = true;
      this.updateLinks();

      if (this.getNewPageFile() === this.oldContainer.dataset.prev) {
        goingForward = false;
      }

      TweenLite.set(this.newContainer, {
        visibility: 'visible',
        xPercent: goingForward ? 100 : -100,
        position: 'fixed',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        right: 0
      });

      TweenLite.to(this.oldContainer, 0.6, { xPercent: goingForward ? -100 : 100 });
      TweenLite.to(this.newContainer, 0.6, { xPercent: 0, onComplete: function() {
        TweenLite.set(_this.newContainer, { clearProps: 'all' });
        _this.done();
      }});
    },

    updateLinks: function() {
      PrevLink.href = this.newContainer.dataset.prev;
      NextLink.href = this.newContainer.dataset.next;
    },

    getNewPageFile: function() {
      return Barba.HistoryManager.currentStatus().url.split('/').pop();
    }
  });

  Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
    return MovePage;
  };
});
```

Tweenmax.min.js: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.1/TweenMax.min.js

Bootstrap.css: [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com)

I got most of this code from one of the examples on the barba page([barbajs.org/demo/nextprev/index.html])

I'm really bad with javascript and things like this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You have to place the barba.js wrapper and container within the body tags. You also have to initialize Barba.js when the DOM is ready.

```
Barba.Pjax.start();
```

I don't see that called anywhere. I also don't know if you have the code for the transition between pages included in any of your .js files.

See http://barbajs.org/transition.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Adding the `defer` attribute to the `<script>` tag did the job for me.
Like `<script defer src="barba.js"></script>`
That will cause the script to wait until the DOM is fully loaded. 
Also, be sure to place a `/` before the path at your `href`. 
Like `<a href="/Page2.html"`

Hope it fixes your Issue!